# Adding Special Tokens Changes all Embeddings - TF Bert Hugging Face

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, huggingface-transformers

Given the following,

```
from transformers import TFAutoModel
from transformers import BertTokenizer


bert = TFAutoModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')
```

I expected that if special tokens are added to the tokens, the remaining tokens would remain the same and yet they do not. For example I expected that the following should be equal but all the tokens change. Why is this?

```
tokens = tokenizer(['this product is no good'], add_special_tokens=True,return_tensors='tf')
output = bert(tokens)

output[0][0][1]
```

[image]

```
tokens = tokenizer(['this product is no good'], add_special_tokens=False,return_tensors='tf')
output = bert(tokens)

output[0][0][0]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When setting `add_special_tokens=True`, you are including the `[CLS]` token in the front and the `[SEP]` token at the end of your sentence, which leads to a total of 7 tokens instead of 5:

```py
tokens = tokenizer(['this product is no good'], add_special_tokens=True, return_tensors='tf')
print(tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(tf.squeeze(tokens['input_ids'], axis=0)))
```

```
['[CLS]', 'this', 'product', 'is', 'no', 'good', '[SEP]']
```

Your sentence level embeddings are different, because these two `special` tokens become a part of your embedding as they are propagated through the BERT model. They are not masked like padding tokens [pad]. Check out the [docs](https://huggingface.co/docs/tokenizers/python/latest/api/reference.html#tokenizers.Tokenizer.add_special_tokens) for more information.

If you take a closer look at how Bert's Transformer-Encoder architecture and attention mechanism works, you will quickly understand why a single difference between two sentences will generate different `hidden_states`. New tokens are not simply concatenated to existing ones. In a sense, the tokens depend on each other. According to the BERT author Jacob Devlin:

> I'm not sure what these vectors are, since BERT does not generate meaningful sentence vectors. It seems that this is doing average pooling over the word tokens to get a sentence vector, but we never suggested that this will generate meaningful sentence representations.

Or another interesting [discussion](https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/significance-of-the-cls-token/3180/9):

> [...] The value of CLS is influenced by other tokens, just like other tokens are influenced by their context (attention).

Comment: Yes the special tokens are of course added. The question is why it seems that all the embeddings seem to change. Look at what I am doing - the first and second embeddings in the list should both represent 'this' but they are not the same.

Comment: Updated answer. Sorry for the lack of clarity

Comment: Yeah I guess that makes sense - the weights of the attention layers, matrix multiplication happens etc so they all change?

Comment: Exactly...attention is at the very core of transformer models.